# How do I use SQL parameters with python?

Tags: python, pymssql

I am using python 2.7 and [pymssql 1.9.908](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/).

In .net to query the database I would do something like this:

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Customer where CustomerId = @CustomerId", connection))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);
    //Do something with the command
}
```

I am trying to figure out what the equivalent is for python and more particularly pymssql.  I realize that I could just do string formatting, however that doesn't seem handle escaping properly like a parameter does (I could be wrong on that).

How do I do this in python?

Comment: Excellent question and answers. Does anyone know how to use *NAMED* parameters like Jason has above. So far I've only be able to use %s, %d type of stuff (positional).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After creating a connection object `db` run [db.execute(query, params)](http://www.pymssql.org/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.execute):

```
cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = %s', [customer_id])
```

then use any of the `fetch...` methods of the resulting `cursor` object.

Don't be fooled by the `%s` part: this is NOT string formatting, it's parameter substitution (different DB API modules use different syntax for parameter substitution -- pymssql just happens to use the unfortunate `%s`!-).

Comment: Thanks.  The `%s` syntax was throwing me off.

Comment: @Jason, you're welcome -- and the possible confusion is exactly why I call that syntax for DB API parameters "unfortunate" (though many popular DB API modules use it, alas).

Comment: Damn this misleading %s syntax! I just spent an hour trying to understand why my code complained for attempt to use %d for specifying an int parameter. I was led to think that it's the Python formatting that's in use here.

Comment: Note that the latest pymssql on python3 doesn't like `[customer_id]`, it wants a tuple `(customer_id,)`