# String replacement in SQL Query using Python

Tags: python, sql, parameters, str-replace

I have two queries in SQL which are the following:

```
q1 = select date_hour from table
```

And, the second query is:

```
q2 = select date(date_hour) from table
```

The only difference between these queries is the string **date_hour** and **date(date_hour)**. SO, I tried parameterising my query in the following manner:

```
q1 = select %s from table
cur.execute(q1,'date')
cur.execute(q1,'date(date_hour)')
```

However, this throws an error which is:

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the comma in `cur.execute` to `%`

Change this:

```
q1 = "select %s from table"
cur.execute(q1,'date')
cur.execute(q1,'date(date_hour)')
```

to:

```
q1 = "select %s from table"
cur.execute(q1 % 'date')
cur.execute(q1 % 'date(date_hour)')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear wich sql library you're using but assuming it uses the Python DB API:

Sql parameters are typically used for values, not columns names (while this is possible using stored procedures).

It seems you're confused between string formatting in python and sql parametized queries.

While %s can be used to format a string (see [formatting strings](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)) this is not the way to set sql parameters.

See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410455/how-do-i-use-sql-parameters-with-python) to use sql parameters in python.

By the way i can't see anything wrong with this simple code:

```
cursor=cnx.curor()
query="select date_hour from table"
cursor.execute(query)
query="select date(date_hour) from table"
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: I don't want the same query to be written twice. The two queries are exactly same except for one difference.That is why, i want to parameterize them.

Comment: As i said parameters are meant to be used for values not columns name. Still if you really insist on using the same string this should do the trick: `cur.execute('select %s from table1' % 'date_hour')`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this:

`q1 = "select %s from table"
cur.execute(q1,['date'])
cur.execute(q1,['date(date_hour)'])`

Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)