# Python, String Variable in MySql Statement

Tags: python, mysql, string, variables

I am using python to get data from an xbee radio.  In the payload is the MY address. I want to SELECT from my MySql database, the row which has that MY address.  I am having trouble using the string variable from python in the mysql statement. Apparently this is different from normal bash or php.

My code:

```
...
sa = response['source_addr'].encode("hex")
...
cursor = connection.cursor ()
cursor.execute("""SELECT label from sensors WHERE radio_address= $sa""",)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row[0]
...
```

The problem is the MySql syntax where I am using the $sa variable.  I have tried several combinations including previous ones that work, but this is the first python use. Even if I put the variable in quotes, no love.

UPDATE:  changing the line to

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT label from sensors WHERE radio_address='%s'""", (sa,))
```

results in the following response:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listen.py", line 34, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""SELECT label from sensors WHERE radio_address='%s'""", (sa,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '7810''' at line 1")
```

where "7810" is the resolution of the variable and is correct, however there appears to be a python syntax error.  I suspect with the versions.

ANSWER:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT label from sensors WHERE radio_address = %s', (sa,))
```

Thanks to IVAN for the question relation. The answers for that previous post are the ones I was looking for.

Comment: `'SELECT label from sensors WHERE radio_address= "$sa"'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use SQL parameters with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410455/how-do-i-use-sql-parameters-with-python)