# Search for an element in SQL

Tags: python, sql

I am writing a python script to search if an element pre-exists in my sql database.

```
 def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    main(conn)    #function with inserts creates table and inserts values and calls find_values() function

def find_values(conn):
    sql = ''' SELECT link_ID from links_table where link_ID="l_1234"  '''
    conn.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

Here I am comparing to something which I have already entered in my code like **"l_1234"**. How will I compare it to something which is dynamic like a user entered variable? 
Also how will I find if the element was found?

Comment: Look into using a prepared statement which can accept a placeholder.  Then, bind the value `l_1234` to the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this post :

[How do I use SQL parameters with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410455/how-do-i-use-sql-parameters-with-python)

or this one :

[How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

From one of the last post:

```
# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```