# How to solve Sql Query Error in Airflow with Python

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I user to Airflow GCStoBigqueryOperator
N write Query with f-string

Already my Data in GCS N use Query n Select data Driven Bigquery

My Data in GCS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHcvg.png)

My Operator Query

```
puuid = _puuid()
sql = f'SELECT * FROM game WHERE puuid={puuid};'
```

Then error occur column

```
column"ptQZI4tcQ7a9KCL74omce0ctYCf4--6csx6j1CBgFUmuyB0XrGZElURF0K3_0ym9TVbykLVi_mqh9w"does not exists Line 1: SELECT * FROM game where puuid=ptQZI4tcQ7a9KCL74omce0ctYCf4--6csx6j1CBgFUmuyB0XrGZElURF0K3_0ym9TVbykLVi_mqh9w
```

I think

```
SELECT * FROM game WHERE puuid='ptQZI4tcQ7a9KCL74omce0ctYCf4--6csx6j1CBgFUmuyB0XrGZElURF0K3_0ym9TVbykLVi_mqh9w'
```

is not error

how to change my code??

Comment: It's more about this line, I think: _"sql = f'SELECT * FROM game WHERE puuid={puuid};'"_, see also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410455/how-do-i-use-sql-parameters-with-python

Answer (score 0):

String values has to be surrounded by qoutes. I guess it should be like this:

```
puuid = _puuid()
sql = f"SELECT * FROM game WHERE puuid='{puuid}'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!!! Solve this problem